# How do i resolve this code errors in NetBeans 8.1

Tags: php, laravel, netbeans, ide

I am using NetBean IDE to code Laravel. I face this errors even i using correct coding. How can i find the solution to this ?

[image: code errors]

Comment: Remove that `<?php` part before that `@extends` and all done

Comment: Thanks, do you have any idea about installing a required plugin into NetBeans ? to use Laravel

Comment: Nope I think there is no any of plugin available for Laravel on NetBeans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel have it's own template engine named as `blade`. In your case, if you use `blade` template with **PHP** `tag` (`<?php`) it should be closed as well with `;?>`. So remove the `<?php` tag or close it, this should solve your problem. Again I think, now  there is no plugin for laravel in Netbeans IDE.